# Bau von "der Monat Januar"

Tags: phrase, noun, time, genitive

"Der Monat Januar" wird zu "the month of January" im englischen übersetzt. Aber soll es nicht "der Monat Januars"? Ich sage das, weil Genitive Form von Januar 'Januars' ist und die Bedeutung zu Genitiv nur hinweißt.

Comment: Der Genitiv von Januar ist sowohl "Januar" als auch "Januars", wobei beides wohl nichts mit Deiner Frage zu tun hat. Aber ehrlich gesagt, verstehe ich die Frage nicht ganz.

Comment: Okay, that was my terrible stab at German. I am just asking whether "Monat des Januar" is ok or not. You say Januar is also its genitive form, right? And why I am asking this question is because I wanted to say 'the month of January' but internet told me to write 'der Monat Januar' and not 'der Monat Januars' as I predicted.

Comment: I am also not aware what exactly your question is. What I can say for sure is that in German there isn't any construction like "Der Monat Januars", "Der Monat von Januar" etc. But perhaps you could offer the full sentence you're intending to write.

Comment: I got it. I was just doing a literal translation which was the wrong way to approach it. Thanks! It feels a little silly now. :|

Comment: This triggers an interesting counter-question: Why is it "the month of january" instead of "the month january" in English? It's not the month belonging to January, is it?

Comment: "Der Monat Januar" ist wie "der Kater Mikesch".

Comment: @JoachimSauer: No, it's not the *possessive genitive*. They call it *appositive genitive*. I'd say it's a type of Genitivus explicativus, where a noun specifies the preceding noun: the month of January, the city of Hamburg, the title of President. It's in Latin languages too: French: le mois de janvier, la cité de Hamburg. Spanish: el mes de enero, la ciudad de Hamburgo. I would guess it's been adopted from Latin, just not by continental Germanic languages. We do have  'die Figur des jungen Werther' or 'der Titel des Präsidenten' for a Genitivus explicativus, though.

Comment: @TehMacDawg: it was not necessarily adopted from Latin: [*"...CONSTITUTAM IN MENSEM **IANUARIUM...**"*](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/legagr1.shtml) (Cicero). But there are also Latin quotes that say *"Ianuariis"*, i.e.the genitive case.

Comment: @TehMacDawg: thanks, I knew that there was a reason, now I even know the name.

Comment: @Takkat: I guess it might as well have sneaked in via the French language since French was pretty big in the Britain of the Middle Ages.

Comment: @TehMacDawg: yeah this may well be possible, but the Latin traces are not bad either (actually this was my first guess too but then I found the *Cicero* quote).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Der Monat Januar* bedeutet im Deutschen nicht *der Monat des Januar*.

Es ist ein Ausdruck wie "Der Tag X", "Der Abteilungsleiter Herr Mayer" ...

Comment: Okay! Ich glaube, ich verstehe es jetzt. Danke für die andere Ausdrücken. Ich fühle mich ganz dumm zur Zeit! Aber ich dachte nie wie es.